# Serialport: Changing DatareceivedHandler

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

When opening the port I add the handler and it works.
What I need is, at some point, to change the handler to another subroutine..
What I did was:

```
AddHandler serport.DataReceived, AddressOf handler1
```

And the first handler worked as expected...
after some time in code I do:

```
RemoveHandler serport.DataReceived, AddressOf handler1  
AddHandler serport.DataReceived, AddressOf handler2
```

But the second handler doesn't work. it never gets called.
What can I do?

I also have coded this routine to open a port :

```
Public Function OpenSerial(ByRef serialport As String, ByVal receivehandler As SerialDataReceivedEventHandler) As SerialPort
    Dim ser As SerialPort
    ser = New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(serialport, 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)
    With ser
        .Handshake = Handshake.None
        .ReadBufferSize = 10000
        .ReadTimeout = 500
        .WriteBufferSize = 10000
        .WriteTimeout = 500
        .RtsEnable = True
        .DtrEnable = True
        AddHandler .DataReceived, receivehandler
        AddHandler .ErrorReceived, AddressOf sErrorHandler
        .Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
        .Open()
        .DiscardOutBuffer()
    End With
    OpenSerial = ser
End Function
```

So I thought I could use it in this way:

```
Dim comSerial As SerialPort
comSerial = OpenSerial("COM1", AddressOf Handler1)
```

Anyhow, however I do it I get the same result: the first time, the first handler works,   when redefined, even if the port is closed and reopened, the second handler never gets
called :(

Comment: A description of the application would help us see what you are trying to do.  One thing I notice is that you have no handshaking and then turn on RTS.  As Hans said, using a boolean will let the handler perform two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was bogus.

The program works fine. I was not receiving any data for another reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this because I need my code to be clean and not a mess as usual :)

Anyhow the device is communicating all the time and I need to magae different types of outputs depending on what I need to do.

In one case I get some blocks of data in other case I get different data and in others I send blocks of data.

This approach worked perfectly doing this (te be safe):

```
Public Sub OpenSerial(ByRef Serialport As String)
    comSerial = New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(Serialport, 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)
    With comSerial
        .Handshake = Handshake.None
        .ReadBufferSize = 10000
        .ReadTimeout = 500
        .WriteBufferSize = 10000
        .WriteTimeout = 500
        .RtsEnable = True
        .DtrEnable = True
        AddHandler .ErrorReceived, AddressOf sErrorHandler
        .Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
        .Open()
        .DiscardOutBuffer()
        .DiscardInBuffer()
    End With
End Sub
```

Then I have subs like this:

```
Sub Dump()
        comSerial.DiscardOutBuffer()
        comSerial.DiscardInBuffer()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        AddHandler comSerial.DataReceived, AddressOf DumpHandler
        {....DO THINGS....}
        RemoveHandler comSerial.DataReceived, AddressOf DumpHandler
        comSerial.DiscardOutBuffer()
        comSerial.DiscardInBuffer()
End Sub
```

And different handlers for every sub.
That works very nicely.
The 1000 ms wait is just for safety but I never had a race condition till now even without it.